# Control layout parameters with Python/Pandas plotly/cufflinks

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I'm trying to figure out how to control the layout of plotly generated graphs using cufflinks. For example: This code will generate a graph with the yaxis lables on the left side. How can I move the Y axis labels to the other side of the graph?

```
import pandas as pd
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, plot,iplot

df.iplot(kind='scatter',mode='lines+markers',x='Time',title='Events over Time',
                       y='Events',margin={'l':450})
```

I searched on the web for a while, so here I am :).

Plotly APIs are here: https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-yaxis-side

I'm having trouble figuring out how to apply this one though:

side ( enumerated : "top" | "bottom" | "left" | "right" )

Determines whether a x (y) axis is positioned at the "bottom" ("left") or "top" ("right") of the plotting area.

Answer (score 3):

You can return the entire figure using the `asFigure=True` attribute of the `iplot` method. Once you have the figure you can update the underlying plotly layout accordingly.

```
_data = df.iplot(kind='scatter', mode='lines+markers',
                 x='Time', y='Events', 
                 title='Events over Time', asFigure=True)
_data['layout']['yaxis'] = dict(side='left')
_data.iplot()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `layout` argument to the `iplot` function to set it directly in `iplot`. Note that this will overwrite all the layout options that were passed directly as kwarg to `iplot()` method, for example `title` arg.

If you want to keep it you have to pass it to the `layout` dictionary too

```
import cufflinks as cf 

cf.go_offline()

df = cf.datagen.lines(2, columns=['Time', 'Events'])
title = 'Events over Time'
layout = dict(yaxis=dict(side='left'),
                  title=title)

df.iplot(kind='scatter',mode='lines+markers',x='Time', y='Events', layout=layout)
```